# giveall=TRUE in error() from the ftsa package in R returns error

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to use the error() function from the R CRAN ftsa package. 
When I set the option giveall=TRUE, so results for all the available methods are returned, R output is:

```
Error en length(insampletrue)  : insampletrue' is lost
```

I tried with the example provided by the error function help site,

```
error(forecast = 1:5, forecastbench = 6:10, true = 11:15, method = "mrae")
```

changing it to:

```
error(forecast = 1:5, forecastbench = 6:10, true = 11:15, giveall=TRUE)
```

But I got the same result. 
Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for drawing my attention to this question. There is a coding error in the error function in the ftsa:::mase, ftsa:::mdase and ftsa:::rmsse functions. There is an argument missing, which displays the error message when giveall = TRUE. I shall submit an updated version and upload it to cran. Alternatively, feel welcome to send me an email at HanLin.Shang@gmail.com, and I am happy to disseminate the code to you asap.

Kind Regards & Many Thanks:
Han